# Customers Cannot Login to Magento in Safari

Tags: php, cookies, authentication, safari, magento-1.7

I have an issue in our Production store where customers currently cannot login with Safari browser.  Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc all work fine.  We are running Magento 1.7.0.2.

I have tried the usual tricks like commenting out items in the $cookieParams array in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php and also changing Cookie life time in Magento Admin.

Despite all this the issue persists.  Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution for it?  Or does anyone have any tips for troubleshooting?  Cheers.

Comment: Ok so after some troubleshooting I have changed the cookie domain to .domain_name.com.  After clearing the cookies for the website in both browsers, they can both login.

Unfortunately the flip side to this, is that customers who had already logged in/visited the website, can no longer log in as they have the old cookies.  Is there any way to expire, just the old cookies?

Answer (score 2):

In your admin pannel, under System >> Config >> Web,

Be sure to set cookies config like  :

```
Cookie Lifetime: 86400
Cookie Path: /
Cookie Domain: www.foobar.com
Use HTTP Only: No
Cookie Restriction Mode: No
```

Thanks to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16349/double-frontend-cookies-causing-intermittent-login-issues

If it still doesn't work, try un-commenting items in app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

Comment: Leaving the Cookie Domain empty has always worked -- this sounds as a bug

Comment: Might be related to this excerpt From the Safari Developer FAQ:

Safari ships with a conservative cookie policy which limits cookie writes to only the pages chosen ("navigated to") by the user. This default conservative policy may confuse frame based sites that attempt to write cookies and fail.